# Set slide potentiometer values

Tags: programming, potentiometer

I am using the Grove - Slide Potentiometer (http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Slide_Potentiometer). How can I set the potValue so that at maximum it will 128?

```
int potPin= A0;   
int readValue;   
int potValue;  

void setup() {
  pinMode(potPin, INPUT);   
  Serial.begin(9600);       
}

void loop() {
 readValue = analogRead(potPin);   
 potValue = (255./500.) * readValue;  
 Serial.print("You are writing a value of ");   
 Serial.println(potValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map` function, see https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/.

Example: If your pot meter gives values from 100 to 1000 and you want to map that range to a range of 0 to 128 you can easily write:

```
potValue = map(readValue, 100, 1000, 0, 128);
```

High likely, in your case and if the potentiometer is 'perfect' it returns values from 0 to 1023 and you can write:

```
potValue = map(readValue, 0, 1023, 0, 128);
```

Comment: with potValue = map(readValue, 0, 1023, 0, 128); I get the max value of 186.

Comment: What is the maximum raw value you get? … you can increase the value of 1023 to assume a higher  maximum (set it to the maximum value you get from the pot).

Comment: the mx. value of readValue is 728

Comment: According to the documentation, map(728, 0, 1023, 0, 128) should be something like 91.  (728/1023*128). If you would use map(value, 0, 728, 0, 128) you should get values upto 128.

Comment: Consider that map is using integer arithmetics (truncating). To get evenly spaced areas, you'd rather `map (readValue,0,1024, 0,129);`( Will transform 0..1023 to 0..128 and everything > 1016 will show 128)   **If this is really what you want.**

Answer (score 3):

analogRead() returns 0x0000 to 0x03ff

If the max data 0x03ff is shifted to the right by 3 bits (or divide by 8), 
then 0x03ff becomes 0x007f, or 127.

I think this will do it:

```
desiredMax = analogRead(A0) >> 3; // divide 1023 max by 8, becomes 127 max
```

Comment: fast and simple, but less readable. +1

Comment: Less readable?  // add a comment to the line

Comment: No need for (less readable) bitshifting - dividing by 8 yields the same compiled code as the right shifts (https://godbolt.org/z/V82L6Z)